# Unable to find next element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to have multiple elements on a page which will toggle visibility of the next content span when the a header span is clicked. All the content span contents are hidden on document ready.

The toggle of content works when targeting the entire class but not when trying to target the next content span element on from the header span being clicked.

The particular markup is being used as we are trying to manipulate text entered via a telerik radeditor

http://jsfiddle.net/hn5ss2au/

HTML

```
<p>
   <span class="collapsibleHeader">Content Header</span><br />
   <span class="collapsibleContent">Sed dignissim velit non congue consequat.</span>
</p>

<p>
   <span class="collapsibleHeader">Content Header</span><br />
   <span class="collapsibleContent">Sed dignissim velit non congue consequat.</span>
</p>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.collapsibleContent').hide();
    $('.collapsibleHeader').click(function (e) {
        $(this).parent().next('.collapsibleContent').toggle();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: The `.next()` function only looks at the one sibling element following the starting point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going up one level, to the `p` element, then `next` to the next  element (see next note), but `.collapsibleContent` is a child of that `p` and a `<br/>` is actually the `next()` element to the `p` (so the filter does not match anything either). `next()` only ever returns the *next* element, *then* applies the filter to see if it matches.

Drop the `parent()` and use `nextAll()` with your selector:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.collapsibleContent').hide();
    $('.collapsibleHeader').click(function (e) {
        $(this).nextAll('.collapsibleContent').toggle();
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('.collapsibleContent2').hide();
    $('.collapsibleHeader2').click(function (e) {
        $('.collapsibleContent2').toggle();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/hn5ss2au/3/

You can use `siblings()` with the same filter, but it is slower than `nextAll()`. If there happen to be more than one of each match, also add `first()`

e.g.

```
$(this).nextAll('.collapsibleContent').first().toggle();
```

Note: `nextall` *is* faster than the alternatives of `siblings()` and `parent().children()`: http://jsperf.com/jquery-next-vs-siblings/5

Answer (score 1):

The reason why next isn't working is because you're using `parent()`.

Inside the `click` callback function, you're calling `$(this).parent()`. When the callback is called, `$(this)` will be `.collapsibleHeader` so when you call `.parent()`, it will return the `p` tag.

To get the `.collapsibleContent` you must call `.children('.collapsibleContent')` as opposed to `.next()`.

Your code will be as follows:

```
$(this).parent().children('.collapsibleContent').toggle();
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qetcd7o4/

Comment: Note: `parent().children(filter)` is considerable slower than using `nextAll(filter)`: http://jsperf.com/jquery-next-vs-siblings/5

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the parent and then .next() will get you the next paragraph element rather than your content. There's no need to hit parent in this scenario. You need to fetch the siblings of the clicked element that have the class .collapsibleContent. Fetching next on the clicked elem also won't work because technically your next elem after the header is a break tag. the following will do that trick:

```js
 $('.collapsibleHeader').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).siblings('.collapsibleContent').toggle();
 });
```

Comment: Same solution as `nextAll()` (only a tad slower). Always best to include the direction if known (`nextAll`, `prevAll`) *if* you can :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie You're right, nextAll is certainly faster. Thanks. http://jsperf.com/jquery-next-vs-siblings/4

Comment: `nextAll` only has to navigate a subset of the adjacent DOM nodes. I think `siblings()` does the same as `parent().children()`.

Comment: Also `nextAll` (and siblings) are faster than a raw `parent().children()`: http://jsperf.com/jquery-next-vs-siblings/5